# Cropping a captured photo. Do I have to store the image to a file on the device first?

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop

I have written an Android app which involves using the device camera to take a photo. I am able to display it in a ImageView without saving it to the device file system directly. I end up saving the photo to a SQLite embedded database along with a few pieces of text from EditText fields in the same activity.

I want to be able to crop the image before displaying the image and ultimately saving it in the database. After numerous Internet searches, and from the all the information I have found ([an example](https://www.androidlearning.com/capture-crop-image-device-camera/) steps 4, 5, and 6 ) the bitmap returned from the camera **has** to saved to the device file system first and a path sent to the cropping feature of the camera.

**Is there a way to send a captured bitmap directly to the camera cropping feature without having to save the image to the device file system?**

I want to skip saving a file the the file system. There is no need to do so.

Comment: You can take the pic, crop it and save it after that, it will save the cropped image and the size will shrink a little from the original one if you crop it a little bit

Comment: Is there a way to send a captured bitmap directly to the cropping app without having to save the image to the device file system? , this is happening because you are saving it when you take it, and after that you are working with it and save it again cropped, can you share your code?

Comment: `have written an Android app which involves using the device camera to take a photo. I am able to display it in a ImageView without saving it to the device file system directly.`. That is not possible. You will have used the thumbnail instead. No need to crop.

Comment: "I end up saving the photo to a SQLite embedded database" -- SQLite on Android is not a good choice for large blobs, like images. I recommend that you save them as files. "Is there a way to send a captured bitmap directly to the cropping app without having to save the image to the device file system?" -- ask the developers of the cropping app. Nobody else can tell you, as nobody else know what cropping app you planning on using. I am not sure why you think the user will have this cropping app, though. Consider using [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: @CommonsWare I put in the code as found in the tutorial I included a link for, and the image is being passed to the crop feature of the camera.

Comment: @greenapps The small size of the images is all that is needed.

Comment: "the image is being passed to the crop feature of the camera" -- there is no "crop feature of the camera". [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are dozens of pre-installed camera apps across the ~10,000 Android device models. There are dozens more camera apps that the user might install. None have to support that undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action. [Use an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: @ CommonsWare Is that why I am getting a null 'data' in the "onActivityResult" method? My built in camera app has a crop feature. It's curious that there are so many tutorials out there, mostly having the same code, that try to teach you how to do this feature. I have settled, for now, to use the "Center Crop" setting on my ImageView. I have to remember to create apps for use with all device to a certain API level.